# Изменение состояния кнопки и простой счетчик на Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Здравствуйте. У меня есть две задачи.
1) Есть такой код - http://jsfiddle.net/xayke/ мне нужно, чтобы вводимая сумма умножалась на некий фиксированный коэффицент (0,9 в данном пример), причем это должно происходить мгновенно. Например, пользователь добавляет ноль к 10, получает 100 и в span 9 сразу меняется на 90.
2) Код - http://jsfiddle.net/C9bws/ мне нужно, чтобы по дефолту показывалась неактивная кнопка, но если заполнить оба поля, то div меняется на button.
Как мне это реализовать? Раньше я дела с javascript практически не имел. Этот вопрос я уже задавал на одном форуме, но то решение не заработало. Точнее оно работало на jsfiddle, но на локальной машине ничего не получалось (jQuery подключен), поэтому, если возможно, код давайте, например, на pastebin.com

Comment: @anton_, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).@anton_, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот ответ на первый вопрос. Фиксированный коэффициент можно поменять в строке `$("#money_value").text(money * 0.9);`.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#money").bind('input', function() {
                var money = parseFloat($(this).val());
                var result = (money * 0.9).toFixed(2);

                if(!isNaN(money)) {
                    $("#money_value").text(result);
                } else {
                    $("#money_value").text("0");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input id="money" type="text" name="money" value="100" pattern="\d+(\.\d{2})?"/>
        <span>Зачислится <strong id="money_value">90</strong> руб.</span>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Вот ответ на второй вопрос. Обратите внимание что верстку необходимо будет отредактировать в js коде, поэтому будьте внимательны и экранируйте символы двойных кавычек.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <style>
        .settings_button { background:green}
        .settings_button_locked {background:gray; width:250px;}
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            function validate() {
                var old_pass = $("#settings_pass_old").val(),
                    new_pass = $("#settings_pass_new").val();

                if(old_pass & new_pass) {
                    $("#button").html("<button type=\"submit\" class=\"settings_button\">Сохранить (активная)</button><br /><br />");
                } else {
                    $("#button").html("<div class=\"settings_button settings_button_locked\">Сохранить (неактивная)</div>");
                }
            }

            $("#settings_pass_old").bind("input", validate);
            $("#settings_pass_new").bind("input", validate);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <label for="settings_pass_old"><span>Старый пароль</span></label><br />
        <input type="password" class="settings_input"  id="settings_pass_old"/><br />
        <label for="settings_pass_new"><span>Новый пароль</span></label><br />
        <input type="password" class="settings_input"  id="settings_pass_new"/><br />
        <div id="button">
            <div class="settings_button settings_button_locked">Сохранить (неактивная)</div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!  Только если, например, ввести число 1002, то количество знаков после точки пугает воображение. Как сделать округление, хотя бы до двух знаков после точки?

Comment: Ща сделаем)

Comment: Добавлено округление до двух знаков после точки.

Comment: Еще раз огромное спасибо.

Comment: все отлично, только применение жквери для данного примера вообще не оправданно

Comment: То есть можно сделать все на чистом Javascripte? Не поделитесь?